# Pandas sort by group aggregate and calculate sum of two colums

Tags: python, eclipse, python-2.7, csv, pandas

I want to do some analysis on data. So far I am enable to group the columns that I want, now i need to add two columns here is my logic:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar',
                           'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar'],
                'B' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'two',
                          'two', 'two', 'one', 'two'],
                'C' : [-1,2,3,4,5,6,0,2],
                'D' : [-1,2,3,4,5,6,0,2]})


grouped = df.groupby(['A','B']).sum()
print grouped
```

The output looks like this:

```
          C   D
A   B          
bar one   2   2
    two  12  12
foo one  -1  -1
    two   8   8

[4 rows x 2 columns]
```

What I need now is two use some addition operation to add column C and D and generate a output like this:

```
A   B       Sum   
bar one     4
    two    24
foo one    -2
    two    16
```

Any ideas will really help me as i am new to python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define a new column `Sum`:

```
In [107]: grouped['Sum'] = grouped['C']+grouped['D']
```

Now `grouped` would look like this:

```
In [108]: grouped
Out[108]: 
          C   D  Sum
A   B               
bar one   2   2    4
    two  12  12   24
foo one  -1  -1   -2
    two   8   8   16

[4 rows x 3 columns]
```

To select just the `Sum` column (as a DataFrame use double brackets):

```
In [109]: grouped[['Sum']]
Out[109]: 
         Sum
A   B       
bar one    4
    two   24
foo one   -2
    two   16

[4 rows x 1 columns]
```